# convergence of a succession of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Can you help me with this problem?

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ 
define $f_{n} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f_{n}(x)=f(\frac{x}{n})$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

a)Find $g= \lim_{n\to \infty} f_{n}$

b) Prove the convergence on a) is not necessarily uniform.

I think, $g=f(0)$ but is just my intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for b):

Suppose $f_n(x) \to f(0)$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Then, given $\epsilon >0$, there exist $n_0$ such that $|f(\frac x  n) -f(0)| <\epsilon$ for all $x$ and all $n >n_0$. Let $t$ be any real number. Put $x=tn$ in this with $n=n_0+1$, say. You get $|f(t)-f(0)| <\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this implies $f(t)=f(0)$. Hence $f$ is a constant. The converse also holds trivially, so the convergence is uniform iff $f$ is a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correc: since $f$ is continuous,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f\Bigl(\frac xn\Bigr) = f\Bigl(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac xn\Bigr)=f(0).$$

Comment: for part b) Do I need to choose a $x$ such that $f_{n}$ does not converges to $f(0)$?

Comment: $f_n(x)$ ùalways* converges to $0$, but not at a uniform speed, i.e., for any $\varepsilon$, you cannot  find $N$ such that $|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$ and *any* $x$. In other words, $N$ depends on $\varepsilon$, of course, but also on $x$.